# index.tsx:25 Matched leaf route at location "/profile" does not have an element. - Warning preventing navigation

Tags: reactjs, aws-serverless

I am not able to render the "profile" component leveraging the following code. When calling the function it simply states that there is not a component to call. I am not seeing anything wrong here. Working on the latest versions of react.

**Error Message:** Matched leaf route at location "/profile" does not have an element. This means it will render an  with a null value by default resulting in an "empty" page.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Nav from './Nav'
import Public from './Public'
import Profile from './Profile'
import Protected from './Protected'

const Router = () => {
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState('home')
  useEffect(() => {
    setRoute()
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', setRoute)
    return () =>  window.removeEventListener('hashchange', setRoute)
  }, [])
  function setRoute() {
    const location = window.location.href.split('/')
    const pathname = location[location.length-1]
    setCurrent(pathname ? pathname : 'home')
  }
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Nav current={current} />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Public}/>
        <Route exact path="/protected" component={Protected}/>
        <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
        <Route component={Public}/>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}

export default Router
```

Profile.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Button } from 'antd'
import { Auth, Hub } from 'aws-amplify'
import Container from './Container'
import Form from './Form'


function Profile() {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('made it here--------------->>>>>>>>>>>')
        checkUser()
        Hub.listen('auth', (data) => {
            const { payload } = data
            if (payload.event === 'signOut') {
                setUser(null)
            }
        })
    }, [])
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null)
    
    async function checkUser() {
        try {
            const data = await Auth.currentUserPoolUser()
            const userInfo = { username: data.username, ...data.attributes, }
            setUser(userInfo)
        } catch (err) {console.log('error: ', err) }
    }
    function signOut() {
        Auth.signOut()
        .catch(err=> console.log('error signing out: ', err))
    }
    if (user) {
        return(
            <Container>
            <h1>Profile</h1>
            <h2>Username: {user.username}</h2>
            <h3>Email: {user.email}</h3>
            <h4>Phone: {user.phone_number}</h4>
            <Button onClick={signOut}>Sign Out</Button>
        </Container>
        );
    }
    return <Form setUser={setUser} />
} 

export default Profile
```

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: can you provide the code for the profile component

Comment: Added to the end

Comment: can i also see your Form component in the profile

Comment: also what version of react router are you using